# How to add extra directory as resources on spring-boot+jersey web application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-boot, jersey

I am using spring-boot as my web application and jersey as my restful api implementation. I need to add images browser abilities on my application. The images are under a extra directory and want the spring-boot can browse these images for users. What I did is as below code.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger =Logger.getLogger(Application.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);

        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/urlPath/*")
                .setCachePeriod(0)
                .addResourceLocations("build/images");
    }
```

When I open the url I always got below error. It seems that the url is coming to jersey and not the spring. How can I resolve this problem in jersey or spring?

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet com.cooltoo.config.JerseyConfiguration threw exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet com.cooltoo.config.JerseyConfiguration threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet com.cooltoo.config.JerseyConfiguration threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context.
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:274)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:221)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.register(ResourceConfig.java:453)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:385)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:172)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:364)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.30 logs.
```

Comment: The error is cause by what [this person is asking](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35863127/2587435). Are you trying to do this somewhere? That's what the stacktrace suggests. It doesn't seem related to the code you posted. I would need more context to help you diagnose.

Comment: I am not using spring-mvc. I am using jersey as the restful API implementation. The code I added is trying to serve an extra directory to be accessed by the browser through the "urlPath". I got the error then open the "urlPath" from the browser. So my code doesn't work in this case. I want to find a way to solve this problem.