# Spring boot runtime add controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jersey-2.0

Is it possible for springboot/spring-mvc or Jersey to add controller (& methods) at **runtime** ?

Meaning when running , user may input a controller name ( such as `user` ) , and method name `sayHello` , and submit , and `/user/sayHello/` is enabled without restarting spring server ?

(As to **what to response** , that's beyond the scope , just assume reply 'OK' )

If spring cannot achieve it , which JVM rest framework supports such functionality ?

It seems jersey can [Programmatically build API Resource](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/resource-builder.html) , but how about **runtime** ?

Comment: It's not possible to modify the runtime ResourceConfig. I've seen questions with attempts to completely _reload_ a _new_ ResourceConfig at runtime, but 1) I saw no resolution, 2) I don't know if that is what you want.

Comment: What do you mean by _"/user/sayHello/ is enabled_"? In the first paragraph you wrote _"add controller (& methods) at runtime"_, which is something different.

Comment: In JAX-RS terms , /user is a Resource , and  /sayHello is a path . Same thing , just different terms. My point is , how to achieve 'runtime add such thing' , so that `/user/sayHello` will not output 404 Not Found or other server exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve this result by using URI templates in your request mapping.  Assuming the number of variations is finite and you can abstract your request mappings to the least amount required.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{var1}/{var2}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpStatus handleRequest(@PathVariable String var1, @PathVariable String var2) {
    callSomeService(var1, var2);
    return HttpStatus.OK;
}
```

The above example would catch your "/user/sayHello" request, or any other request which contains 2 parts in the path.  If you have some more complex variations, you could create request mappings accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

It's not posible to register new route in the Dispatcher Servlet after the load of the application context.

You can create a controller method to "catch" a variety of requests with a wildcard

```
@RequestMapping(value="/custom/**", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public T handle() {...}
```

and then route the request manually in the method body.